# How can i get the value inside the child and put it on a array

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

heres a image of my database:

[image: heres a image of my database]

heres my code

```
Query countQuery = databaseReference.child("evacuation").orderByChild("evacuationNumber");

List<Places> placesList = new ArrayList<>();

countQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
        Places places = snapshot.getValue(Places.class);
        Sampleviewtxt.setText((CharSequence) places);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code? I.e.: if you set a breakpoint on each line and run the code in a debugger, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.